# Implement a Brute Force Function Into My Caesar Cipher Code

Tags: python, function, brute-force, caesar-cipher

Can someone please help me create a function for my Caesar Cipher code that brute forces all the possible key outcomes? As of right now, my brute function prints out the correct encrypted messages, but it won't print only that message of the key. For example, (HOWDY! Hello.) given key one would give an output of (1 LSAHC! LIPPS.), which is correct, but when it moves onto the next key, it gives an output of (2 LSAHC! LIPPS.KRZGB! KHOOR.). The output includes both messages of key 1 and 2 and I want it to just include the message assigned to each key.

What my code is supposed to output:

```
Do you wish to encrypt, decrypt, or brute force a message?
Enter your message:
Your translated text is:
1 LSaHc! Lipps.
2 KRZGb! Khoor.
3 JQYFa! Jgnnq.
4 IPXEZ! Ifmmp.
5 HOWDY! Hello.
6 GNVCX! Gdkkn.
7 FMUBW! Fcjjm.
8 ELTAV! Ebiil.
9 DKSzU! Dahhk.
10 CJRyT! CZggj.
11 BIQxS! BYffi.
12 AHPwR! AXeeh.
13 zGOvQ! zWddg.
14 yFNuP! yVccf.
15 xEMtO! xUbbe.
16 wDLsN! wTaad.
17 vCKrM! vSZZc.
18 uBJqL! uRYYb.
19 tAIpK! tQXXa.
20 szHoJ! sPWWZ.
21 ryGnI! rOVVY.
22 qxFmH! qNUUX.
23 pwElG! pMTTW.
24 ovDkF! oLSSV.
25 nuCjE! nKRRU.
```

What my code actually outputs:

```
Do you wish to encrypt, decrypt, or brute force a message?
Enter your message:
Your translated text is:
1 LSAHC! LIPPS.
2 LSAHC! LIPPS.KRZGB! KHOOR.
3 LSAHC! LIPPS.KRZGB! KHOOR.JQYFA! JGNNQ.
4 LSAHC! LIPPS.KRZGB! KHOOR.JQYFA! JGNNQ.IPXEZ! IFMMP.
5 LSAHC! LIPPS.KRZGB! KHOOR.JQYFA! JGNNQ.IPXEZ! IFMMP.HOWDY! HELLO.
6 LSAHC! LIPPS.KRZGB! KHOOR.JQYFA! JGNNQ.IPXEZ! IFMMP.HOWDY! HELLO.GNVCX! 
GDKKN.
7 LSAHC! LIPPS.KRZGB! KHOOR.JQYFA! JGNNQ.IPXEZ! IFMMP.HOWDY! HELLO.GNVCX! 
GDKKN.FMUBW! FCJJM.
8 LSAHC! LIPPS.KRZGB! KHOOR.JQYFA! JGNNQ.IPXEZ! IFMMP.HOWDY! HELLO.GNVCX! 
GDKKN.FMUBW! FCJJM.ELTAV! EBIIL.
9 LSAHC! LIPPS.KRZGB! KHOOR.JQYFA! JGNNQ.IPXEZ! IFMMP.HOWDY! HELLO.GNVCX! 
GDKKN.FMUBW! FCJJM.ELTAV! EBIIL.DKSZU! DAHHK.
```

etc....

My Full Code:

```
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
message = ""
encryptedmessage = " "
decryptedmessage = " "
keynumber = 0
count = 1
number = 0

def encrypt():
  global message
  global encryptedmessage
  global keynumber
  print()
  print()
  message = str(input("Enter your message:"))
  print()
  print()
  keynumber = int(input("Enter the key number (1-26)"))
  print()
  print()
  for i in message:
    position = alphabet.find(i)
    if position == -1:
      encryptedmessage += i
    else:
      newPosition = (position + keynumber) % 26
      encryptedmessage += alphabet[newPosition]
  print("Your translated text is:")
  print(encryptedmessage)


def decrypt():
  global message
  global encryptedmessage
  global decryptedmessage
  global keynumber
  message = str(input("Enter your message:"))
  print()
  print()
  print()
  print()
  keynumber = int(input("Enter the key number (1-26)"))
  print()
  print()
  print()
  print()
  for i in message:
    position = alphabet.find(i)
    if position == -1:
      decryptedmessage += i
    else:
      newPosition = (position - keynumber) % 26
      decryptedmessage += alphabet[newPosition]
  print("Your translated text is:")
  print(decryptedmessage)


def brute():
  global message 
  global encryptedmessage
  global decryptedmessage
  global keynumber
  global count
  global number
  keynumber = 1
  print()
  print()
  message = str(input("Enter your message:"))
  print()
  print()
  print("Your translated text is:")
  while keynumber < 26:
    for i in message:
      position = alphabet.find(i)
      if position == -1:
        decryptedmessage += i
      else:
        newPosition = (position - keynumber) % 26
        decryptedmessage += alphabet[newPosition]
    print(str(keynumber) + decryptedmessage)
    keynumber = keynumber + 1

action = input("Do you wish to encrypt, decrypt, or brute force a message?")

if action == "encrypt":
  encrypt()
if action == "decrypt":
  decrypt()
if action == "brute":
  brute()
```

Comment: You should consider changing `decrypt` and `encrypt` to functions that takes two parameters. Text and shift (int). Like `encrypt('aa', 2)` would return `cc`, etc. From then it should be easier for you to deal with the problem.

Comment: It's alright, I just ended up doing a simple fix: just reset the decryptedmessage string at the start of every loop so it wouldn't just add the same message over and over again. So I would set decryptedmessage = " " under while keynumber < 26.